# JPA/Hibernate - InheritanceType.JOINED behaves like InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to implement a very simple inheritance model in Hibernate.  Basically I have a single superclass which can be called `A`, and several subclasses all of which inherit from `A`.  Since the behavior I'm seeing is the same for all of them, they can just be referred to as `B`.

What I'm trying to arrive at is what's described [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html) in section 6.2.  Basically, there should be a table for `A` that contains its fields, and a table for `B` that contains only the fields that are distinct to the subclass, plus a join column back to the table for `A`.  I am using Hibernate's automatic schema generation (enabled for the development persistence-unit only).

What I see when I look at the schema, however, is a table for `A` the contains its fields (correct), and a table for `B` which contains all the fields in `A` (incorrect), plus the fields added in `B`.  My classes are annotated as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A implements Serializable {
    protected long id;
    protected Date createDate;
    protected String title;
    protected boolean hidden;

    public A() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public boolean isHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }

    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    //also setters...   
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="aId", referencedColumnName="id")
public class B extends A {
    private String extraField;

    public B() {
        super();
    }

    @Column
    public String getExtraField() {
        return extraField;
    }

    //also setter...
}
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?  Specifically, what I want to see when I look at the generated DB schema is something like:

```
Table A:  {id, createDate, title, hidden}
Table B:  {aId, extraField}
```

...and instead what I get is:

```
Table A:  {id, createDate, title, hidden}
Table B:  {id, createDate, title, hidden, extraField}
```

Is this just not possible using Hibernate's automatic schema generation, or have I screwed up the annotations somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your annotation is correct , it should produce the table schema that you want .

But now you get an undesired schema , which is exactly the schema produced using the `Table per concrete class` strategy (i.e `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`). So , I think one of the possible reason is that the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property in your configuration uses the default value , which is `update` .

The behavior of the `update` value is :

- Hibernate will try to create an
  update script to update the database
  schema to the current mapping when
  the `SessionFactory` is created.
- If an update statement cannot be 
  performed , it will be skipped (For 
  example adding a not null column to a
  table with existing data)
- Hibernate will not delete any data
  during the update .(For example , if
  a column 's name is changed , it just
  add an new column with the new name ,
  but still keep the column with the
  original name)

So , I think you must use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)` to generate the schema before , which produced the following schema . Table A and Table B do not have any foreign key associations to each other.

```
Table A:  {id, createDate, title, hidden}
Table B:  {id, createDate, title, hidden, extraField}
```

After that  , you changed to use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` . During the update schema process , hibernate just updated your scheme by adding a foreign key assocation between the `TableA.id` and `TableB.id` . It kept all other columns in Table B . That 's why you get the current schema even though your annotation is correct .

The desired table schema should be generated after you drop Table A and Table B from  the DB before starting the hibernate programe . Alternatively , you can set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create` , then hibernate will delete all tables before generating the table schema .

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I ever used `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`, but in any case dropping the tables and letting Hibernate regenerate the schema as you suggested fixed things.